# Como fazer um JOIN usando o find()?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou tentando fazer um join de tabelas usando o find() do cakephp. Tenho 3 tabelas, sao elas: `users, pessoas e matriculas`. Na tabela `users` eu tenho uma chave estrangeira para a tabela `pessoas` e na tabela `matriculas` tbm tenho uma chave estrangeira para `pessoas`.

Eu quero fazer um JOIN entre essas tabelas, estou tentando mas quando faço o JOIN para a tabela `matriculas` o retorno vem vazio. Não sei o que pode ser, se estou fazendo errado. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
public function doLogin(){
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $json = $this->request->input("json_decode", true);
            $email = $json["User"]["email"];
            $senha = $json["User"]["senha"];

            $sql["conditions"] = array(
                "User.email"=>$email,
                "User.senha"=>$senha,
                "User.status"=>1
            );
            $sql["joins"] = array(
                array(
                    "table"=>"matriculas",
                    "alias"=>"m",
                    "type"=>"INNER",
                    "conditions"=>array("Pessoa.id"=>"m.pessoas_id")
                )
            );

            $users = $this->User->find('all', $sql);

            $array;
            if($users){
                $array = array("status"=>"1", "msg" => "Login efetuado", "result"=>$users);
            }else{
                $array = array("status"=>"0", "msg" => "Usuário ou senha inválido", "result"=>$users);
            }

            return json_encode($array);
        }
```

**Resultado vazio**

```
{"status":"0","msg":"Usu\u00e1rio ou senha inv\u00e1lido","result":[]}
```

**meu projeto ERM**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A forma como você modelando este `Join`, é da versão anterior a 2.x.x!

Correto seria desta forma:

```
...

$conditions = array(

    'conditions' =>  array(

        'User.email' => $email,
        'User.senha' => $senha,
        'User.status' => 1

    ),

    'joins' => array(

        array(
            'table' => 'matriculas',
            'alias' => 'm',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Pessoa.id' => 'm.pessoas_id'
            )
        ),

    ),

);


$users = $this->User->find('all', $conditions);

...
```

Comment: opa, obrigado pela atencao @Coringa ...Eu estou usando o CakePHP 2.7 . Mas resolvi fazer usando `query`. escrevo o SQL e parece q tenho mais controle. Obrigado.

Comment: Vai ser uma dor de cabeça quando precisar de mais de uma tabela, sendo que é só replicar o array dentro da joins, e mudar as config para outra tabela, sem falar que desta forma sua query terá uma melhor semântica e já devida devidamente tratadas, quando precisar efetuar um debug na query. Abraços!

Comment: Não vejo diferença disso que você sugere para o que ele já estava usando.